# What exactly is hanging to the left in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, us

In [Us (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Us_(2019_film)), Abraham drags an unconscious Gabe all the way to the family's boat and then places him inside a bag. Gabe eventually wakes up and successfully throws Abraham overboard. Later on, however, the boat engine fails, and Gabe falls in the water. The boat engine starts itself and the boat 
appraoches near to Gabe:

> Gabe: **It hangs to the left. It hangs to the goddamn left**.

What exactly is hanging to the left in this scene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Hangs" in this context means the boat veers to the left if no one is holding the steering.  It's also a call back to earlier in the movie when he first shows the boat to his family.

> Oh, I got it, I got it. They taught me how to do this. **It veers a little to the left,
>   so you gotta hold on to it.**

Comment: More specifically, this was why the boat came back in a giant circle to where Gabe was swimming; rather than simply continuing to go away from him.